# Accessing Structure array

Tags: java, arrays

```
for (int i = 0; i < row.findRowNumber(); i++) {
  String[] itemTokens = rawInventory[i].split("\\s");
  inventory[i] = new Item(itemTokens[0], Integer.parseInt(itemTokens[1]));
}

for (int i = 0;i < inventory.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(inventory[i]);
}
```

I want to access the structure array of objects called inventory. If I test out to println it will come out as :

```
Item@629a99eb
Item@13ef45e0
Item@41d47f59
Item@65f4cdd2
Item@2af4ca49
Item@2d0c94a7
Item@14f3770c
Item@7c0cbf92
Item@28f549de
Item@7fc4a2d3
Item@469e0c2d
Item@32318293
Item@50739aa3
Item@55ad6c98
```

So how do I deal with array of objects in java? Thanks

Comment: You are already accessing the array and printing references to objects. What output do you expect?

Comment: its suppose to come out as: apple 40 grape 30 etc etc

Comment: Then you have to access the fields of the object accordingly and print them or overwrite the class' `toString` method. Java cannot know how you want the fields to be printed.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) for your data structure `Item` then it will be called on `System.out.println()`.

For instance:

```
String toString() {
  return getName() + " " + getAmount();
}
```

If we assume you have `getName()` to get the name and `getAmount()` to get the amount.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(inventory[i]);
```

inventory list contains objects of `Item` , so inventory[i] will return you object of Item.

Now in order to print, call getter, setter or field name of Item.

eg Item class have two instance variable x, y which are being set in constructor. then what u can do is

```
System.out.println(inventory[i].getX());
```

and if 'x' is public then simply

```
System.out.println(inventory[i].x);
```

or as siggested by others, override toString() method.

Comment: I have two variables, and I want to print it side by side just to test it out first, so, how can I call a getter method on a constructor?

Comment: Nops, if u have defined getter and setter functions for your fields in ur Item class, only then u will be able to call them. Or u can simply do this
System.out.print(inventory[i].variable1);
System.out.print(inventory[i].variable2);
@NikYusofNikFarid

Comment: In order to get fields directly, like System.out.print(inventory[i].variable2);  variable2 should be a public member, which in itself might not be a good practise. @NikYusofNikFarid

Answer (score 1):

Just overwrite method `toString()` of Item class

Answer (score 1):

Your item class needs to override toString().

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `toString()` method in `Item` class. When you implement it the list will include what ever you print in that method for each `Item`.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the `Item` objects.
If you want to have specific output you can implement the `toString()` method in your `Item` class.

Or in your loop access getters like:

```
for (int i = 0;i < inventory.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(inventory[i].getName() + " " + inventory[i].getQuantity());
}
```